# Google api OAuth fails with redirect uri mismatch

Tags: c#, .net, google-search-api, umbraco8

I have a website, where I can create Events for members, and I am trying to connect to google calendar API, so when ever i create a new event, i can then sync that to the calendar.

I have followed this guide: https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/dotnet
But when i get to the part where i run the sample code, and have to authenticate by OAuth.
I get the following:
[image: redirect_uri_mismatch image]

My Code:

```
public class InitializeGoogleCalendarApiHelper : IInjected
    {
        public InitializeGoogleCalendarApiHelper(ILogger logger)
        {
            this.logger = logger;
        }

        // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
        // at ~/.credentials/calendar-dotnet-quickstart.json
        static string[] Scopes = { CalendarService.Scope.CalendarReadonly };
        static string ApplicationName = "Nordmanni Google Calendar API";
        private readonly ILogger logger;

        public CalendarService Initialize()
        {
            UserCredential credential;

            using (var stream =
                new FileStream("C:/Projects/Nordmanni/Nordmanni.App/credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is created
                // automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first time.
                string credPath = "C:/Projects/Nordmanni/Nordmanni.App/GoogleApiToken.json";
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
                logger.Info<InitializeGoogleCalendarApiHelper>($"Credential file saved to: {credPath}");
            }

            // Create Google Calendar API service.
            var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });
            return service;
        }
    }
```

I am running the website locally for now, in visual studio.
The port number changes for each request i have made, so setting the port number does not seem to work.

These are the settings i setup in google.

[image: google console domain settings.]

I have spent the last day and a half, looking for a solution, but have been unable to find anything so far.

I have downloaded the credentials.json and added to the solution.
Any resources or links are welcome, or sample code which i could look at.
I am unsure if i have setup the domains correctly , or if it is even possible to setup while running it locally.

Comment: The URI in your displayed error message (http://127.0.0.1:53479/authorize/) is not in your configured list of authorized URLs, so it seems completely expected.  The port number is important and http://x.com:123 and http://x.com:456 are considered completely different URIs for OAuth2 redirects, so you will need to make changes to have it not change for each request (or even for each execution of the web app).

Comment: @sellotape i tried that as well, but the port number seems to change every time. And the address is not the same as the IIS configured one.

Comment: What sort of web app is it? E.g. .NET/Core ASP?  Angular?  With all of those, my experience is the port is initially set fairly randomly, but stays the same across executions on the same machine, if using IIS Express.  In Core/.NET ASP you can set it in the project's properties > Debug tab, or in Core under project > Properties > launchSettings.json.  Whichever way, there is no getting around it needing to be identical to that configured on Google's side.

Comment: .net mvc, Umbraco project. It has a localhost:1234 address, but when i make the request it says 127.0.0.1:4321 and the port number keeps changing, even though i haven't changed it.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem a while ago, as far as I am assuming you are trying to authorise from your backend service for google API

### **Solution we employed**

We used google service account for that. It is simple and elegant to use

#### Step - 1: Setup google service account

Follow this link to setup a service account using google developer console
https://developers.google.com/android/management/service-account

#### Step - 2: Share your google Application with service account email-id

This step gives your service account access to the google application may it be calendar or google docs or google sheets
Similar to sharing document with other users
https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37082?hl=en (This link shows how to share your calendar with other emailId)

#### Step - 3: Follow these links to integrate service account with your application

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account
https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production

Advantage of google service account is that you don't have to login at regular intervals to update the data. Set it up once and you can forget about it

Hope my answer helps :)

Comment: i am a bit lost on step two ? I Have created a service account, and added a key to it, downloaded the file, and then saved it. But i don't know how to share the calendar app with the email id ?

Comment: Hi, please follow this link, it shows you how to share calendar with email id
https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37082?hl=en

Comment: Also updated the answer incase someone else wants to view the same

Comment: So i ran the sample code, and it seems it ran fine. But how does using a storage client help me get the calenderservice up and running ?